# How to change cell address?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for first non blank cell in column A for a merging range.

I found the last cell with the value in that column, but for merging purposes I need to get one cell below.

```
Sub mergeCells()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=Cells(2), 
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlByColumns)

    s = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1).Address 'one cell above current one 

    MsgBox rng.Activate + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: `rng.Offset(1,0)` will get you to the below cell.

Comment: I might not have understood your problem correctly, otherwise it's simply: `ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Address`. EDIT: Mikku is quick !

Comment: @Mikku, if I try: `rng.Offset(1,0)`  it gives me syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 Sub mergeCells()

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=Cells(1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlByColumns)

  MsgBox rng.Offset(1, 0).Address

  End Sub
```

Comment: Msgbox should give you the address of the cell you are looking for.

Comment: one more thing, can I pass cell address to the variable as such: `s = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1).Address` ? Cause i get error there also: application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Why are you using `Activecell` ?

Comment: cause I assume, when user will need to merge cells, that will be the start point, from there I get to the A column and at the exact cell and it will be one of my range points

Comment: You can use `s = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1).Address` ... It will work, but if your activecell is in 1st column, this will return an error ..as you cannot go `-1` from there

Comment: understood, but how then I could get to the A column to the exact cell. Is there another solution to it ?

Comment: @Ganja ... I am not able to understand the objective.. You should Ask a New Question and clearly state your objective.

Comment: I can't post question so fast as I need answer's as soon as possible. About the objective, I am trying to get cells for a range to merge them.